# Regression coefficient in simple regression

Tags: statistics, regression

Let's say we have two random variables $Y$ and $X$ used to form regression model $$Y=\alpha+\beta X+\mu$$
It also holds that $E(\mu)=0$, $\text{Var}(\mu)=\sigma_{\mu}^2$, $\text{Var}(X)=\sigma_{X}^2$,  $\text{Var}(Y)=\sigma_{Y}^2$, $\text{Corr}(X,Y)=r$ and $\text{Corr}(X,\mu)=r_{X\mu}$. Find $\beta$. I tried to solve this as follows:

For simple linear regression $\beta=\dfrac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\text{Var}(X)}$ and $\text{Corr}(X,Y)=\dfrac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}=r$ so that:
$$\beta=\frac{\text{Corr}(X,Y) \cdot \sigma_X \sigma_Y}{\sigma_X^2}=r\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}$$
Is this as simple as this?

Comment: Assuming, that $\mu$ is a noise with $Cov(X,\mu)=0$ you are correct.Otherwise since you have $r_{X_{\mu}}$ (I just saw it), I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably want the answer for the true $\beta$ given all moments let's be detailed.
$$
E(Y)=\alpha+\beta E(X) \\
XY=X\alpha+ \beta X^2 +X\mu \\
E(XY)=E(X)\alpha+\beta E(X^2)+E(X\mu)\\
Cov(XY)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(X)\alpha+\beta E(X^2)+E(X\mu)-E(X)\alpha\\
-\beta E(X)^2=\beta Var(X)+Cov(X\mu)\\
So\\
r\sigma_X\sigma_Y=\beta \sigma_X^2+r_{X_{\mu}}\sigma_X \sigma_\mu
$$
Thus (FIXED)
$$
\beta=\frac{r\sigma_Y-r_{X_{\mu}}\sigma_\mu}{\sigma_X}
$$

Comment: This is what I was trying figuring out! Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be: $$\beta={r\sigma_Y-r_{X\mu}\sigma_\mu \over \sigma_X}$$

Comment: oh yes, my typo, thanks I will fix it.